# Getting this error: error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-safe-area-context`

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I am getting this error after running my App:

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-safe-area-context` from `node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/vendor/views/Stack/StackView.js`: react-native-safe-area-context could not be found within the project.

But the same thing I had done for my old demo. It worked perfectly fine.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please check my code:

**For installing:**

1. React Native Navigation & Gesture Handler:

`npm install --save react-navigation`

`npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`

2. React Native Stack:

`npm install --save react-navigation-stack`

**App.js**

```js
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import FirstOptionsPage from "./FirstOptionsPage";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    FirstOptions: FirstOptionsPage
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        // backgroundColor: '#28F1A6',
        elevation: 0,
        shadowOpacity: 0
      },
      headerTintColor: "#ca375e",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: "#161616"
      }
    }
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator); // For setting Navigation Stack
export default App;
```

And **FirstOptionsPage.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Switch
} from "react-native";

export default class FirstOptionsPage extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Preferences"
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      switch1Value: false
    };
  }

  toggleSwitch1 = value => {
    this.setState({ switch1Value: value });
    console.log("Switch 1 is: " + value);
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainerStyle}>
        <View style={styles.subContainerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitleTextStyle}>Someone likes my post</Text>
          <View style={styles.switchStyle}>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch1}
              value={this.state.switch1Value}
              thumbColor={MAGENTA_COLOR_CODE}
              trackColor={{
                false: GREY_COLOR_CODE,
                true: DARK_GREY_COLOR_CODE
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to React-Native. How can I fix this?

Comment: check for `react-native-safe-area-context` in your node modules, `react-navigation-stack` requires that but your node modules do not have that

Comment: I had to add `react-native-safe-area-context` to my `package.json` file. I don't understand why this isn't a peer dependency of React Navigation. But, maybe due to version conflict or something. If it needs it, it should be a peer dependency.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `SafeAreaView`, for the new react-native version, it has migrated to `react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view`. if you want to use `SafeAreaView`, you should install it first.

the new use is like this:

```js
import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view';

export default function MyAwesomeApp() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>
          Look, I'm safe! Not under a status bar or notch or home indicator or
          anything! Very cool
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

for installing it you can use the following commands:
`yarn add react-native-safe-area-view react-native-safe-area-context`.

if you do not use auto-link, you have to also link it. for details about it, see this [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view)

Comment: Now I am getting this error ```error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/masked-view` from `node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/vendor/views/MaskedView.js`: @react-native-community/masked-view could not be found within the project.```

Comment: And actually everything was working fine in my previous project. Now it is showing this issue.

Comment: you should know since react-native 0.6, many libraries had removed form react-native core. this problem like pre problem, read this link[https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view]

Comment: Well after doing what you said in your answer I also had to install ```@react-native-community/masked-view``` to fix it. Then my code worked successfully. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, this is written in the release notes https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/releases/tag/v2.0.1

Answer (score 47):

It is a little funny, I wanted to add navigation so I added

`npm install --save react-navigation`

for this to work fine I had to add:
`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

Then I got

> Unable to resolve "react-native-safe-area-context"
> So I added:
>
> `expo install react-navigation-stack`
>
> `expo install react-native-safe-area-view react-native-safe-area-context`

then I got

> `bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module` @react-native-community/masked-view`

So I searched for the masked-view (which currently is not supported by the expo, according to its git document). Then I found out that I can use:

> `expo install @react-native-community/masked-view`,
> which could work or not :)

Therefore, from now on I use following commands at the start of all of my react-native projects, to be able to use navigation properly:

> `npm install --save react-navigation`
>
> `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-navigation-stack`
>
> `expo install react-native-safe-area-view react-native-safe-area-context`
>
> `expo install @react-native-community/masked-view`.

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-screens' 

LOL

Comment: damn it, it's true hahaha

Answer (score 25):

After running these commands:

```
npm i react-native-safe-area-view react-native-safe-area-context &&
react-native link react-native-safe-area-context
```

It prompted me an error about masked-view, so I also had to run `npm i @react-native-community/masked-view` and then my code can now be successfully run on Android physical device.

Thanks to [Lenoarod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5705408/lenoarod) and [Gautam Shrivastav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7257122/gautam-shrivastav) for pointing out the right direction.

Comment: For react native version `0.60` and above, use yarn instead of npm and **do not link**.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I used yarn as suggested by Fatih

Answer (score 15):

installing following two,

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
npm install react-native-safe-area-context
```

it is work for me

Comment: I don't understand why this is not in dependencies list of react-navigation. Anyways installing these two worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I think you miss link depency with your project so you can try as below:

**With React Native 0.6 or higher:**

On iOS, make sure you have [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) installed and run:

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```

**With React native 0.59 and lower try:**

```
react-native link react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 6):

copy all and paste in terminal

```
expo install react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

work for me

Answer (score 3):

Run the following:

```
expo install react-native-safe-area-context
```

`expo` will select the right version and then install it.

Answer (score 3):

To use React Navigation you need to run the following command

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
yarn add @react-native-community/masked-view
yarn add react-native-safe-area-context
```

and it gave me another error on **import type { ScreenProps } from 'react-native-screens'**

then

```
yarn add react-native-screens
```

It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use the commend

```
npm i react-navigation-stack
```

to solve this error

Comment: This is literally what OP said they have already done

Comment: @M-- Why are you editing bad answers instead of flagging them?

Comment: @zoran404 there is nothing wrong with getting the correct formatting. "bad answers" shouldn't be flagged. We can downvote them, and in select cases cast delete votes. If further discussion is needed, please bring it up in SOCVR chatroom. Folks there will know much more than I do. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the Metro Bundler directly from the project directory works for me.

# Clean cache
`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all`

# Start Metro Bundler directly
`react-native start`

# Now run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` in another tab

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @react-native/stack then before installing it use following command to install it's dependency

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

read the documentation at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to incompatible version pairs for expo and safe area context. You should try run this:

```
npm uninstall react-native-safe-area-context
```

Then, you run this :

```
expo install react-native-safe-area-context
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.